# You have used the alias XX in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models. The two fields in the first model fetch the data in the other model by ID. Although it works as I want, when I call the api on different pages, I get the error "You used the CustomsExitUpAd alias in two separate associations. Aliases must have unique aliases". I've looked at similar questions but I don't quite understand how to solve it. Where did I go wrong and how can I fix it?

```
InstallationInstructions.belongsTo(Customs, {as: "CustomsExitUpAd",foreignKey: 'customs_of_exit_id'});
InstallationInstructions.belongsTo(Customs, {as:"CustomsGateUpAd", foreignKey: 'exit_customs_gate_id'});
```

.....

```
const {id} = req.query;
        const agreement = await InstallationInstructions.findOne({
            where: {
                id: id
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: Interlocutors,
                },
                {
                    model: Users,
                },
                {
                    model: Drivers,
                },
                {
                    model: Customs,
                    as: "CustomsExitUpAd",
                },
                {
                    model: Customs,
                    as: "CustomsGateUpAd",
                },
                {
                    model: InstallationInstructionPlates
                },
                {
                    model: InstallationInstructionsUploadAddress
                },
                {
                    model: InstallationInstructionPlates,
                    include:[{
                        model: Vehicles
                    }],
                },
                {
                    model: Interlocutors,
                    include:[{
                        model: InterlocutorContact
                    }],
                },
                {
                    model: SenderBuyer
                }
            ],
        })
```

Comment: Make sure you didn't use `CustomsExitUpAd` alias in other association by mistake. Also make sure you didn't register the same associations twice.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am sending requests from multiple and different pages to the same api. I use the data as CustomExitUpAd while printing the page. Is this why I'm getting a warning?

Comment: I don't think so.